# How to have a image as the plot face (the outer border) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know I can change the color using `fig.patch.set_facecolor("#ccdece")` but how do I have an image instead of a solid color? Like using `img = plt.imread()` and `ax.imshow(img)` but for the outer border.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy `ax` for the full size of the surrounding figure and add an image to that `ax`. Giving the `ax` a low enough `zorder` makes sure it appears behind the actual plots.

For an additional effect, the facecolor of the actual plots can be made semi-transparent.

Here is an example starting from a stock image.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import numpy as np

imageFile = cbook.get_sample_data('ada.png')
image = plt.imread(imageFile)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))

bg_ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], zorder=-1)
bg_ax.axis('off')
bg_ax.imshow(image)
t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 200)
x = 2 * np.cos(t / 2)
y = np.sin(t)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_facecolor('#FFFFFFEE')
plt.show()
```

[image: example figure background image]